# Apache LoadBalancer 'crashes' under the load

Tags: apache, webserver, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I have configured an Apache HTTP server + load balancer (utilizing the mod_proxy_balancer)

When I execute load testing the balancer don't pass most of the load to the backend servers(simple Java App over Tomcat)

I'm not sure if the apache httpd can't handle the load, or is it the load balancer configuration..

This is how my conf file looks like:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://xxxxx.amazonaws.com connectiontimeout=200000 max=50000 timeout=200000 ping=200000
BalancerMember http://yyyy.amazonaws.com connectiontimeout=200000 max=50000 timeout=200000 ping=200000
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /a balancer://mycluster timeout=200000
```

any ideas?

Comment: What does Apache do if it doesn't proxy these requests? What does your client, error log, and access log say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really need some features that Apache provides I'd be tempted to use Varnish or HAProxy instead.

At a guess you're running out of threads and no more connections are being passed to the origin servers until a thread becomes free.

Your timeout / ping values seem quite high - what sort of response times are your expecting to see from the origin servers?

Have you load tested the individual origin servers to see what level of load the can cope with, and what's the load on them like during the load-balanced load test?